# How to force v4l2 settings

Tags: camera, v4l

I discovered that my webcam exposes a control called "LED1_mode". By setting it to zero, it is possible to turn off the status LED while the camera input is still active. Is there a way through v4l2 or directly within udev to prevent an application from setting this control to any value other than the default?

Comment: I guess you could use v4l2loopback and have a proxy application be the only process able to access the actual camera. I wouldn't know how to do it though.